# Word for carefully selecting/filtering information that meet a certain criterion

Tags: single-word-requests

I wrote these comments under another user's answer to the Astronomy SE question [Is phys.org/space-news reliable source?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13787/7982)

> I've added an answer about the "Space News" section, which is what the question asks about. I'll go look at Physics now. I'm curious have you found anything at all that you think is in any way less than reliable information? I think you are trying to suggest that if something is not "proper science journalism" that that makes it less reliable. Yes, a university press-release about a recent Phys Rev Letter can have errors in it, all written material can contain errors, even peer-reviewed. But I am pretty certain these will be few and far-between, and since they link to the source material...
>
> -- which is what we really should be reading for accurate information in the first place -- I think there is nothing wrong with considering **a carefully selected set of news items** to make us aware of them. We can also turn to longer journalistic articles, or the primary sources (the papers themselves) if we want more, but few of us have the bandwidth to do that several times a day.

There is a much better word for "carefully selected" that I can not remember. I keep thinking of "cultivated" or "constrained" which makes me wonder if it begins with the letter "c".

It could be a loose synonym to "filtered".

*It's the thing many of us do here in Stack Exchange as a community effort* - build a collection of questions that are not just any question, but are useful, informative and on-topic by voting (up/down/close) on the question and answer posts.

Comment: Looking for [*curated*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/curate)?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Bingo! Yes that is exactly the answer! I've gone ahead and updated my comment in Astronomy SE. Feel free to post an answer, or if this doesn't rise to the quality level of this highly curated site, I can just delete the question rather than bear the slings and arrows in the form of downvotes downvotes :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use *complete*, which is a single c-word, as in "... a **complete** set of news items ..."

In the mathematical sense the smallest set of basis vectors is a *complete* set necessary to *span all space* in a particular representation. Note that being *complete* does not infer there is only one set of basis vectors -- or only one set of newsworthy perspectives. In cartesian coordinates, a 2/d basis set are two orthogonal lines each of unit length. In polar coordinates, a 2/d basis set are a line of unit length and an angle. Both describe the same space completely.

The use of orthogonal basis infers the concern to curate such carefully written thought.

Philosophically, G.W.F. Hegel's theory of Dialectics, especially the *unity of opposites*, *negation of negation*, and *quality vs. quantity* might be the equivalent of this mathematical analogue from which further curation is derived.

Thus, you could also use *curate*, as in "... a **curated** set of news items ..." as suggested by [Yoself Baskin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/618876/word-for-carefully-selecting-filtering-information-that-meet-a-certain-criteria/618904#comment1575131_618876). It is through the process of curation that one arrives at a *complete* set of newswothy items.

Organically, *holistic* might also fit, if you don't mind breaking with the c-motif toward the greater good.

Aside and unrelated is an awkward and funny use of repeated words, using "... that that ..." in the passage above. Just a thought.

Comment: Excellent point. Response revised per suggestion.

Comment: Much better, you are right.